# Fibonacci Sequence in Python

Tags: python, fibonacci

```
n=raw_input("Enter no. of numbers in Fibonacci series: ")
n=int(n)
fib=[]   
fib[0]=0  
fib[1]=1  
for i in range(2,n):
    fib[i]=(fib[i-1])+(fib[i-2])   
print fib
```

The error I'm getting: IndexError: list index out of range
Help me with the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You are indexing an empty list! you should first create your list like:

> `fib=[]`

and then add each element to it using `append` operator.

> `fib.append(0)`

so here is the correct version of your code:

```
n=raw_input("Enter no. of numbers in Fibonacci series: ")
n=int(n)
fib=[]   
fib.append(0)  
fib.append(1)
for i in range(2,n):
    fib.append(fib[-1]+(fib[-2]))  
print fib
```

Answer (score 0):

You are starting with an empty list but not expanding it. Therefore you are trying to index elements that don't exist.

Use `fib.append()` to add numbers to your list.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> n==raw_input("Enter no. of numbers in Fibonacci series: ")
>>> n = int(n)
>>> fib=[0,1]
>>> for ix in range(2,n):
...     fib.append( fib[-1] + fib[-2] )
... 
>>> fib # result for n is 20
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181]
>>>
```